# Why can't I install an extension?

Tags: gnome, extension, gnome-tweak-tool, gnome-shell-extension

I'm trying to install an extension via the GNOME Tweak Tool.  However when I navigate to the extension directory and click "Open," nothing happens.  The button is being pressed (the press event is stimulated) but the dialog doesn't disappear or change at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The extension should be packaged in a tar.gz file, it should not be a directory (for Gnome Tweak Tool to work). Alternatively you can place the directory in ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions, then it should work.

Comment: It seems that the problem was that the GNOME Tweak Tool doesn't consider anything not matching `^.+@.+$` to be an extension and ergo doesn't display it.